# facebook Admins And App ID Missing: fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

`Admins And App ID Missing: fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.`

the debugger indicates that this issue could in some way be limiting our click-through rates.

Is that accurate? Could it be adversely affecting our click-through rates?

are there any potential privacy concerns for our users as a result of said fix (adding the admin ID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is that accurate? Could it be adversely affecting our click-through rates?**

In an official released paper by implementing the correct open graph tags we should see a 2-3X increase in the click-through rate.

**If it is, what would be entailed in fixing this?**
adding the id of the admin(s)

**And, are there any potential privacy concerns for our users as a result of said fix?**
none so far, since the user is managing their security